# Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial ( USER TOUR )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app

I am confused on this part:
2.2 User Resource on the book

I need help on this I cannot navigate to users or tour users
Using this command: URL Action Purpose /users index page to list all users /users/1 show page to show user with id 1 /users/new new page to make a new user /users/1/edit edit page to edit user with id 1

The error says:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>   You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I am not sure what is wrong with this did I miss something before this step to navigate users?

Comment: What did you type in the browser url and what is your config/routes.rb file look like?

Comment: https://agile-mountain-59355.herokuapp.com/    thats the link to the site .

Comment: MY ROUTES.RB --                                                                                                                        Rails.application.routes.draw do resources :users # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html root 'application#hello' end

Comment: -----MY RAKEFILE-----
-# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake, -# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
require_relative 'config/application
Rails.application.load_tasks

Comment: did you run `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` in console and check that it should generate `resources :user` in `config/routes.rb`

Comment: let me generate hold on

Comment: i figure it out what I did I rerun the whole thing

Comment: and I think after generating scaffold , i miss the heroku run rails db:migrate which is for heroku

Answer (score 0):

At 2.2 all that you've done so far is create a new rails application. You won't be able to navigate to a users resource as there is no controller or model.

The code

```
def hello
    render html: "hello, world!"
  end
```

creates a "hello" action, which simply displays the text "hello world!" MH added a route to the application's root '/' (localhost:3000/ by default) with the line in routes.rb

```
root 'application#hello'
```

At this point, by navigating to localhost:3000 you should see "Hello World!" and that is all.

Keep working through the tutorial and MH will explain everything in great detail. It sounds like you are trying to perform CRUD operations on the users resource. For this you'll need to  scaffold a User model with

```
$ rails g scaffold User name email
```

*Note I've used "name" and "email" as actions here but you can model your User however you see fit. The scaffold command creates the 7 CRUD actions, index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy. It also creates the resourceful routes for each action with the line

```
resources :users
```

So, I recommend continuing with the tutorial. If you want to play around with the CRUD actions it's as simple scaffolding a User resource, running bundle install, and rake db:migrate (or rails db:migrate if you're using rails5.

Comment: thank you I already figured it out! Question on your command rails g scaffold User name email on the terminal .. I dont understand how it looks like can you explain to me that command

Comment: $ 'code' rails g scaffold User first_name last_name email password 'code' This command 'scaffold' is useful because it creates your model, resourceful routes, and views. The 'g' simply stands for generate

Comment: apparently I don't know how to use mini-markdown sorry!

Comment: $ 'rails g scaffold User first_name last_name email password' is the code you would type in the terminal